# Fetch other developer's master branch in separate branch

Tags: git, version-control, github

I've got a GitHub repo that is forked from developer X's repo. Another developer, Y, is developing some interesting stuff in his fork, independently of mine and in his `master` branch.

I'd like to get Y's `master` in my repo, but in a separate branch, which I might later merge into my `master`. What command or `.git/config` stanzas do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should add a "remote" for the developer Y's repository:

```
 git remote add developerY git://whatever
```

Then you should fetch all the branches from that repository as remote-tracking branches:

```
 git fetch developerY
```

(Now if you run `git branch -a` you should see that the remote-tracking branch `developerY/master` has been created.)

To create a local branch based on developer Y's `master`, you would do:

```
 git checkout -b masterY developerY/master
```

You can then work on the `masterY` branch, and when you're ready to merge it, just do:

```
 git checkout master
 git merge masterY
```

Comment: I changed the `git add` to `git remote add` and it worked. Thanks!